# Не меняется версия PHP в PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

Создаю проект в PhpStorm, выбираю интерпретатор Php 7.2. После создания проверяю в терминале командой "php -version"  - пишет PHP 7.0.26. Пробовал и другие версии, тоже самое. В чем может быть причина и что с этим делать?

Comment: Добрый вечер. А почему Вы думаете, что phpstorm должен обновлять версию php?

Answer (score 4):

Настройка версии интерпретатора PHP в PHPStorm позволяет включить правильную интерпретацию кода в IDE и связанные с ней дополнительные возможности https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-local-php-interpreters.html, чтобы обновить версию PHP на локальном/удаленном сервере, нужно предпринять другие действия (как, например, для Ubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/565784/how-do-i-upgrade-php-version-to-the-latest-stable-released-version)

Answer (score 0):

Версию php можно повысить если в "переменных средах" указать папку с php выше версии, я по крайней мере делаю так.